# Should I pay for search engine submission as a web hosting extra?

Tags: seo

When people buy hosting at Go Daddy or other shared hosting, there is a $1.99/month additional fee to be submitted to search engines.

What is involved in that process? How can I do the same thing if my shared hosting provider doesn't offer this service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two biggest search engines are Google and Bing. For Google use this link:
https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url?hl=en_uk

For Bing use this:
http://www.bing.com/toolbox/submit-site-url

You only need to do it once. It's not worth paying that money.

Extra information: If they talk about resubmitting sitemaps then you don't need to do that if your site hasn't changed much: 
[Is it necessary to re-submit modified sitemaps?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/28734/is-it-necessary-to-re-submit-modified-sitemaps)

Comment: so http://freewebsubmission.com/ and http://www.addme.com/ and http://www.submitexpress.com/free-submission.html are useless ?

Comment: Yes they are indeed.

Comment: @menardmam: Services like that may add your site to *other* search engines, too. But in general you can bet that all active search engines will find your site if it is already indexed by Google, Bing, Yahoo, …

Answer (score 3):

If your site is linked to by any other site/page that is already in Google's index then your page(s) will be found and indexed.

Don't go paying money for "search engine submission" it's all snake oil.

Use the links provided by paulmorriss and/or create a sitemap and let Google's Webmaster Tools know about it.

That's all you ever need to do.